# Azure MVC 3 Project - What is the default Admin account password

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, azure

I have just created a new project in VS2010 using the

**Visual c# > Cloud > Windows Azure Project**

template.

When I run it I would like to log in using the Admin account which I know exists in the secMembership table.
I assume there is a password published, but I can't find a reference to it anywhere. Am I missing some documentation somewhere or am I not concerned with this account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the Winodws 8 Toolkit?  If so, try:

User Name: admin

Password: Passw0rd! (with a zero)

Otherwise the password may be just: password

If those don't work, try clicking on the ASP.NET Configuration button at the top of the solution explorer and click on the security tab.  You should be able to create a new user or at least see if there is an admin account already.  Chances are there isn't one yet.

Comment: Thanks for that. Although there is an entry in the table for an Admin, the ASP.NET configuration tool does not show it! Thanks for your help.